# Get NcML from OPeNDAP server

Tags: xml, netcdf, ncml, opendap

Unidata's ToolsUI (java GUI program) can generate NcML from OPeNDAP dataset link, and `ncdump` command line utility can too. I'm wondering if it's possible to output NcML from web service, either as  OPeNDAP feature or a separate web service that can generate NcML from dataset link.

So, is it possible to get NcML response from OPeNDAP server?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've been able to conclude:

ncML is supported by variety of data servers including OPeNDAP, but implementation depends on server maintainers. So one OPeNDAP server may provide support while other may not.

This makes XML interface to datasets partially possible, which was my initial concern.